after HTML form click need to change sub tags from input to something not editable
I have HTML form:
<div class="party-group party-group_has-items" data-field-name="accessLevels">

Here another HTML being generated when click on that "accessLevels" parent
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label control-label_main">Department</label>
    <div class="form-group-content">
        <div class="form-field" data-editors="department">
            <div class="form-field_type_string">
                <span class="form-field__editor-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" class="form-field__editor form-field__editor_autosize"/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

I am trying to chnage th input tag to something not editable when click on the parent "accessLevels". The change needs to be done only for "accessLevels" section
Currently found solution like this
    $(document).on('click', 'div[data-field-name="accessLevels"] .form-field__editor', function() {
        $('div[data-field-name="accessLevels"] .form-field__editor').prop('readonly', true);
    });

However, this readonly change happens not right away when I click on parent section
It's make an effect when I click inside of child input form
Could someone advise what's happening please?

Right now, you added your click handler in a way that it will only fire if you click the input element itself. If you want it to apply when clicking on some ancestor element higher up already - then modify the selector accordingly ...?

Remove

.form-field__editor
from the selector. And added code, if clicked element is not the parent to return, so it does not activate also on click on child element.

        $(document).on('click', 'div[data-field-name="accessLevels"]', function(e) {
console.log(e.target)
if (e.target !== this) {
    return;
}
    
    $('div[data-field-name="accessLevels"] .form-field__editor').prop('readonly', true);
});

